# Help with Exercise 6.9.2 in Weibels "An introduction to Homological Algebra

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, group-extensions

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let

$0 \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow Y \overset{\rho}{\longrightarrow} X \longrightarrow 1 $

and

$0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow X \overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} G \longrightarrow 1 $

be central extensions. Show that the composition

$0 \longrightarrow \mathrm{ker}(\pi \circ \rho)  \longrightarrow Y \overset{\pi \circ \rho}{\longrightarrow} G \longrightarrow 1 $

is a central extension of $G$. If $X$ is a universal central extension of $G$, conclude that every central extension splits.

I am lost on the first part of the question. I thought about using the property that for the surjective group homomorphism $\rho$, the center of $Y$ will be mapped into the center of $X$, however I did not make any progress with this idea. For the second claim I understand how I can construct a candidate for a right split using the "universal property" of universal central extensions by applying the result before, but this only delivers a homomorphism $f \colon X \longrightarrow Y$  such that $ \pi = \pi  \circ \rho \circ f$ (with the notation from before) and not $\rho \circ f = \mathrm{id}_X$. Any tips are greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: It doesn't look right. $Y$ could be any nilpotent group of class 2, such as the dihedral group of order 8, $B = Z(Y)$ (so $X$ is abelian), $A=X$ and $G$ is trivial, in which case $\ker(\pi \circ \rho) = Y$, and the extension is not central. Is the group $Y$ perfect perhaps?

Comment: @DerekHolt In the book is no such condition mentioned, but this exercise gets used later in a proof, where $X$ is assumed to be perfect. Does that change anything?

Comment: Yes I think is correct if $X$ is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim that $0 \to K \to Y \overset{\pi \circ \rho}{\to} G \to 1$ is a central extension, where $K := \ker(\pi \circ \rho)$ is false in general.

For a counterexample, let $Y$ be nilpotent of class $2$,  such as the dihedral group of order $8$, $B := Z(Y)$, $X := Y/B$, $A:=X$, and $G$ trivial. Then  $K=Y$, so the extension in question is not central.

It is true however if either $Y$ or $X$ is assumed to be perfect.

Note that $B \le K$ and $K/B \cong A$. We have $[Y,K],Y] = [[K,Y],Y] \le [Y,B] = 1$ so, by the three subgroups lemma, $[[Y,Y],K] = 1$. So if $Y$ is perfect then $[Y,B]=1$ and we are done.

If $X$ is perfect then $Y = [Y,Y]B$, so $[Y,K] = [[Y,Y]B,K] = [[Y,Y],K][B.K] = 1$, so the extension in question is central.